# How to delete items on the left of value1 and on the right of value2 in a list of ints in Python?

Tags: python, list, slice

Let's say I have this list:

```
l = [5, 4, 2, 7, 1, 8]
```

I want to keep 2 and 1 and everything in between them and delete everything else, what is the most elegant way to achieve this? What I would like to get, is this:

```
l = [2, 7, 1]
```

In other words, I know the value of the item on the left and the value of the item on the right, and I need them and everything in between. The rest should be deleted.

This is not elegant, but it's fast

```
start = l.index(2)
del l[:start]

end = l.index(1)
del l[end+1:]
```

This seems pretty pythonic, but is very slow:

```
l = [val for val in l if l.index(2) <= l.index(val) <= l.index(1)]
```

With a list of 10000 ints the first one is about 100 times faster and uglier. How to get the best of both worlds?

**EDIT:**

I decided to try out the different answers and see how fast they run.

```
s = l.index(start)                         #1
e = l.index(end, start) + 1
l = l[s:e]

l = l[l.index(start):l.index(end)+1]       #2
l[:] = l[l.index(start):l.index(end)+1]    #3
```

1 becomes significant compared to 2 when the length of the list is in the order of magnitude of 10 million and the index of the starting point is in the millions. At most (with a list of 10 million ints), we are talking about a few hundredths of seconds of performance gain with my pretty fast laptop using one thread.

3 is clearly the slowest and uses the most memory.

Comment: In your second example, you call `index` three times for each iteration. So basically you change O(n) to O(n**2).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l[l.index(start): l.index(end) + 1]
```

How about this?

Comment: Ahh, that's sweet. Gotta love Python. It's like pulling yourself up with your own hands. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to modify the list instead of creating a new one, you can do `l[:] = l[l.index(2):l.index(1)+1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can start scanning for the `1` starting from the index of the `2` instead of starting at the beginning again

```
L = [5, 4, 2, 7, 1, 8]
start = L.index(2)
end = L.index(1, start) + 1
L[start: end]
```